# how to create a function to call the modal pop up?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create several buttons to call different modal popup functions but all I can do is create a function by copying it. Is there a more concise way?

```js
function setSelectedPelanggan() {
  // Mengatur nilai input teks dengan opsi yang dipilih
  var selectedOption = $('input[name=optionsRadios]:checked').val();
  var optionText = $('label[for=option' + selectedOption + ']').text();
  $('#selectedPelanggan').val(optionText);

  // Menutup popup
  $('.modal').modal('hide');
}

function setSelectedVendor() {
  // Mengatur nilai input teks dengan opsi yang dipilih
  var selectedOption = $('input[name=optionsRadios]:checked').val();
  var optionText = $('label[for=option' + selectedOption + ']').text();
  $('#selectedVendor').val(optionText);

  // Menutup popup
  $('.modal').modal('hide');


  function clearSelection() {
    // Membersihkan pilihan radio button saat popup ditutup
    $('input[name=optionsRadios]').prop('checked', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Show Modal 1</button>

<!-- Button to trigger modal 2 -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Show Modal 2</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do here. What is a "modal popup function"? Chances are you should be calling those functions from a modal element, which we can't see. Please revise your post to build a more complete demo using the editor. Include Bootstrap via CDN. Also tag your Bootstrap version. See [ask] and take the [tour] for more information.

Comment: I created you a snippet. Please add the modal divs to make it a [mcve]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You just need an abstract function.
Example:

```
// HTML
<button name="modal1" class="modal-btn" type="button">Button 1</button>
<button name="modal2" class="modal-btn"type="button">Button 2</button>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <button class="close-modal">a</button>
</div>
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <button class="close-modal">b</button>
</div>
```

```
// CSS
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```
// SCRIPT
function openModal(modalName) {
 $(`#${modalName}`).show()
}

function closeModal(modalName) {
 $(`#${modalName}`).hide()
}

$('.modal-btn').on('click', function() {
    openModal(this.name)
})

$('.close-modal').on('click', function() {
    closeModal($(this).parent().hide())
})
```